# Constrain Wikipedia Search API to generate only NS:0 pages

Tags: api, redirect, generator, wikipedia

I am calling the Wikipedia API from Java using the following search query to generate redirected pages:

https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=allpages&gapfilterredir=redirects&prop=links&continue=&gapfrom=D

where the final 'D' is just an example for the continue-from.

I am interested in only iterating over items in namespace:0. In fact, if I don't, the continue return value includes category pages, which break the next query iteration.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, can you show the exact (continued) query that does include a category page?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter you need from the [Allpages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aAllPages) api is

```
…&gapnamespace=0&…
```

but notice that when you omit it, then `0` is the default anyway.

Comment: My problem is that the following generator is working now for NS:0 but still returning category pages (with titles including the colon character) which fail on the follow-up continuation query.  http://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=allpages&gapfilterredir=redirects&prop=links&gapnamespace=0&continue=&gapfrom=C99

Comment: No. Those are no category pages. Those are redirects in the main namespace which point to category pages. And non-working ones as well, because the `C:` is an interwiki prefix for Wikimedia Commons, which makes them completely inaccessible other than [by their pageid](https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=3168342&redirect=no). Fascinating.

Comment: You should get all those pages deleted (I'm sure there's a policy against cross-namespace redirect in the pt wp as well, and as they don't work they should be deleted anyway), and you might file an upstream bug against mediawiki that the title of an existing page is considered invalid.

Comment: I now understand better that (1) they are redirects to category pages available only by their pageid, and (2) it's probably a bug that they're there. In the meantime, my generator is getting stuck, because the continue_from parameter is pointing to one of them, which returns an error? Any suggestions?? Many thanks.

Comment: [Throwing up the `limit`s](http://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=query&generator=allpages&gapfilterredir=redirects&prop=links&gapnamespace=0&continue=&gapfrom=C99&gaplimit=500&pllimit=500) seems to help. If it doesn't (because you still hit right in that section), you might use the last page name from the result that is not a `C:` one, continue with that and filter out possible duplicates.

Comment: Thank you; I appreciate your advice. My problem with using the last page that is not a C: one is there are more than 'limit' of them. Therefore, I can't get past them. What seems to work is a kludge to just jump ahead to 'CA', skipping the 'C\punct*'.

Comment: Are there? I count [only 17 of them](http://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=query&list=allpages&apfilterredir=redirects&apnamespace=0&apfrom=C9z&aplimit=500). Btw: Have you issued the deletion requests already? If no, I'd do it.

Comment: Good idea! (Embarrassed to tell you I have no idea how to issue the deletion requests.)

Comment: @BobR: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipédia:Esplanada/geral#Deletion_request_for_invalid-named_redirect_pages